# Is it okay for a struct to have default value invalid?

Tags: c#, class, struct

Consider the following struct

```
public struct ResizeFactor
{
    public readonly float Horizontal;
    public readonly float Vertical;

    public ResizeFactor(float horizontal, float vertical)
    {
        if (horizontal <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");
        if (vertical <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");

        Horizontal = horizontal;
        Vertical = vertical;
    }
}
```

It feels like a 'value'.
It's small and immutable.
It looks and feels 'struct'y.

But there's the default value problem... It doesn't feel right to have ResizeFactor with Horizontal = Vertical = 0 as default value.

Example:

```
var myResizeFactor = new ResizeFactor();
// myResizeFactor.Horizontal = 0
```

I know I could use a class instead and just 'disable' the default parameterless constructor, but that's not really the point here.
The question is: is it legit to create such struct? One with a invalid default value?

Last but not least: it this the right place to a question like this? Or should I post somewhere else, like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I belive that feature was removed before the release.

Comment: And it wouldn't have been used in all cases anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try very hard to make the default value valid, yes. For example, you could do something like:

```
public struct ResizeFactor
{
    private readonly float horizontal;
    private readonly float vertical;

    public float Horizontal => horizontal == 0f ? 1.0f : horizontal;
    public float Vertical => vertical == 0f ? 1.0f : vertical;

    public ResizeFactor(float horizontal, float vertical)
    {
        if (horizontal <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");
        if (vertical <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");

        this.horizontal = horizontal;
        this.vertical = vertical;
    }
}
```

This means that the default *internal* representation has an *effective* value of (1f, 1f) — a no-op resize, basically.

We use the same approach in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) where various value types can contain a reference to a time zone — which we deem to be UTC if the value is null.

Note that this is one of the benefits of exposing properties instead of fields... the internal details become less relevant.

As an aside, I think actually a "resize to 0" is entirely reasonable as a factor. After all, if you allow `float.Epsilon` that would resize almost anything to either 0 or very, very small anyway... is there really that much difference between that and resizing to 0?

Answer (score 0):

if you [omit the new keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx) when declaring the struct you can apparently get a struct with uninitialized, invalid values:

> When you create a struct object using the new operator, it gets
>   created and the appropriate constructor is called. Unlike classes,
>   structs can be instantiated without using the new operator. In such a
>   case, there is no constructor call, which makes the allocation more
>   efficient. However, the fields will remain unassigned and the object
>   cannot be used until all of the fields are initialized.